# Simple Fields in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, embedded-ruby

I have written this line in my `show.html.erb` of `Person` model.

```
 <%= f.simple_fields_for :holidays do |holiday| %>
   <%= holiday.input :number,
                     :label => holiday.day.name,
                     :input_html=>{
                       :required => false
                     } %>
```

I have two questions :

`1.` What does holiday mean here. I mean what does it contain?

`2.` `:label => holiday.day.name` line gives an error => `undefined method day`.

There is a join table `holidays` which contains (`person_id, day_id, number)`.

Comment: you need to do `holiday.object.day.name`... `holiday` is form builder object.

Comment: "I mean what does it contain" - really? It is very easy to see for yourself what it contains exactly. Just stop at a breakpoint there or write `holiday` to logs/markup.

Comment: And second, if you get an error, post it in its **full version**. By omitting what you think is irrelevant information, you might actually cut off the most interesting part in that error. In this case, it is "undefined method 'day' for **what kind of object**"?

Comment: I know that much of programming to stop the code and see the object. Buy, what I was doing was seeing the 'holiday' variable instead of 'holiday.object'. 'holiday' variable contained a lot of crap which I wanted to know about. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`holiday` is form builder object.

To get the object which is wrapped inside a form builder object, you need to call the `object` method on it. The below will work.

```
holiday.object.day.name
```

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you have holidays association in `Person` model:

1. `holiday` here is same as `f` in `<%= form_for @person do |f| %>`, which is a form builder object.
2. The error occurs because `holiday` itself is not an instance of the model, but a form builder object. So you shall need to do something like `holiday.object.name`